Is it possible to add field in a table visual that shows an indicator (such as red/yellow/green icon) as well as text?
Looking for some functionality akin to a Power BI screen, like this:

Is it possible to do this without a custom visual? Trying to do this on OSS Grafana.
Have so far tried value mappings, converting the field to a gauge. Read about adding in HTML text within table columns but this doesn't seem to be supported in recent versions.

No icon. But Grafana allows you to color cell text or cell background.

Value mapping + (quite ugly) regex + emoji - might(!) work. Alternatively, you can duplicate column, and use normal ranges in value mapping with the same emojis.

AFAICT, regex approach works. But if your column has numeric type you might have to convert it to string first for regex to work.

@markalex can you please elaborate on regex approach or point me to a link / example where I can find more information on it? The column is numeric.

First, add transformation convert to type, select column and type string. Then add override for that column, select value mapping, add regex (100|[89][0-9]) ✅ $1. This will add check mark to values from 80 to 100. Add more overrides as needed.

Thank you @markalex I was able to figure it out based on your comments. You can add a custom column to the dataset with a value and a colour indicator as an example, then use a RegEx value mapping like this to achieve the desired look: (\d+.\d+) (\bGreen).

You can add a custom column to the dataset with a value and a colour indicator as an example, then use a RegEx value mapping like this to achieve the desired look: (\d+.\d+) (\bGreen).
